# How to censor/unlock content in a Kid-safe (4+) app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rating, profanity

I'm working on an unabridged dictionary app. My goal is to release a 4+ rated app which schools can freely purchase.

The nature of language is that some words are profane, disparaging, vulgar, or otherwise offensive. I have carefully identified words and definitions which are offensive, vulgar or could be considered inappropriate for children. My app can hide/censor them.

What's the best way to release a 4+ app, while also providing a way for adults to unlock the full dictionary, completed with profanity and all the offensive words?

One idea would be to require a free in-app purchase (free non-consumable In-App Purchase) to unlock the offensive content, plus the option to set a password to re-lock offensive content. The idea being that a responsible party/adult would need to authorize it.

Other ideas or best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I am ultimately using is a **free, non-consumable, in-app purchase**. The theory is that in a school, only the administrators will be able to make in-app purchases. So for our purpose (unlocking unabridged content), it meets the goal. Ditto for parents who are keen to maintain control over their devices/apps.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to just make something unique. Since there is lot of dictionaries out there which provides offensive and adult words, no one is going to buy in app for offensive words. Perhaps censored dictionary for kids is something parents or school might willing to pay.

Comment: Hi. Good point. I think I was unclear. I have a unique dictionary, which contains interesting and new content which will differentiate it in the marketplace from other dictionaries. The dictionary has over 600k items, roughly 1k of which are censored. The issue is that I want to censor it by default. Many adults will want it uncensored because there are many legitimate words that are lost. It's not just the "motherf---ers" which are censored, but other words of lexicographic interest that are kind of on the boundaries, including racial slurs and insults of various degrees.